# Nodejs Bookshelf. How to use BETWEEN filter

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I want to filter DB table by timeStamp of element.

Table got rows :
ID, URL, timetable.

How to filter data by timestamps in some range? 
Like usual in SQL ... BETWEEN firstTime AND lastTime

I tries something like:

```
  if (first_date && last_date) {
        Pages.forge()
            .where("Date", '>=' , first_date)
            .where("Date", '<=' , last_date)
            .fetchAll()
            .then(function (pages) {
                res.send(persons.toJSON());
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                res.send('An error occured');
            });
```

Comment: What happened when you ran that code? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Try the answer from this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41417730/select-object-created-between-two-dates-by-bookshelf-mysql-knex-on-node-js

Answer (score 2):

```
model.query({where: {"Date", '>=' , first_date}, orWhere: {"Date", '<=' , last_date}})
      .fetch()
      .then(function(model) {
        // ...
      });
```

you must use where and or where for example:between means any of two conditions but here you set to both condition true .

Answer (score 1):

If you add `.query()` to call chain you will be able to use knex syntax inside.

To your example:

```
      Pages.forge()
          .query(function(knex) {
              knex.whereBetween('Date', [first_date, last_date]);
          })
          .fetchAll()
          .then(function (pages) {
              // do something with pages
          }).catch(function (error) {
              // do something with error
          });
```