# Select object created between two dates by Bookshelf, MySQL, Knex on node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, bookshelf.js

I need to get a list of an object created between two times;

I am able to get data by writing SQL Query;

But I need to write this query by Bookshelf;

My simple query:

```
    router.route('/locations')
  // fetch all locations
  .get(function (req, res) {
    Locations.forge()
    .fetch()
    .then(function (collection) {
      res.json({error: false, data: collection.toJSON()});
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      res.status(500).json({error: true, data: {message: err.message}});
    });
  })
```

how can I get location between two dates like above query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding a `query()` call to the chain, like

```
Locations
  .forge()
  .query(function(qb) {
    qb.whereBetween('creation', [initialDate, finalDate]);
  })
  .fetch()
  .then(function (collection) {
    res.json({error: false, data: collection.toJSON()});
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    res.status(500).json({error: true, data: {message: err.message}});
  });
```

See Bookshelf [Collection.query()](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-query) and Knex [Query Builder](http://knexjs.org/#Builder) and [whereBetween()](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereBetween)

Comment: @flavoidesousa Thanks, this code work for id but it does not work fine for date object! Is anything missed?

Comment: For answering at that level lots of information missing. Table schema, sample data, the behavior, output or error messages you are getting, the parameters you are using and so on.

Comment: The problem was on response type and by convert to Date, I received true response.

Comment: That doesn't help much. The code and data that generated the error, the exact error message should be starting points. Since this problem is no longer the query constraint, you should create a new SO question with as much information as possible.